# Why won't asdoc generate?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex-mobile, asdoc

I'm trying to generate an asdoc right now. The project is two classes. One class extends `View` and another is a custom `Event` class. Really, really simple. I cannot, for the life of me, get the asdoc to properly generate. I've tried so many different commands, I've forgotten what I've actually tried and haven't.

Every time I compile, I get the following output:

```
/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/src/com/vuria/ui/views/PanelViewBase.as(41): col: 37 Error: The definition of base class View was not found.

    public class PanelViewBase extends View
                                       ^

/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/src/com/vuria/ui/views/PanelViewBase.as(204): col: 31 Error: Method marked override must override another method.

        override protected function createChildren():void {
                                    ^

/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/src/com/vuria/ui/views/PanelViewBase.as(246): col: 32 Error: Method marked override must override another method.

        override public function set navigationContent(value:Array):void {
                                     ^

/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/src/com/vuria/ui/views/PanelViewBase.as(262): col: 32 Error: Method marked override must override another method.

        override public function set actionContent(value:Array):void {
                                     ^

/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/src/com/vuria/ui/views/PanelViewBase.as(279): col: 31 Error: Method marked override must override another method.

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
                                    ^
```

Here is the bash script I am using

```
#!/bin/bash
docSource="/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/src"
docOut="/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/documentation"
libraryPath="/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.11 AIR 3.9/frameworks/libs"
packageDescriptions="/Users/jjanusch/dev/workspaces/AIR/library/asdocs-package-descriptions.xml"

"$asdoc" \
    -doc-sources "$docSource" \
    -output "$docOut" \
    -lenient \
    -compiler.library-path "$libraryPath" \
    -package-description-file "$packageDescriptions" \
    -keep-xml=true \
    -skip-xsl=true
```

There are plenty of Flex classes involved in the `PanelViewBase` class, but the only mobile component is `View`. I've been unable to find any similar issues where a mobile class can't be documented. Does anyone have any idea why this won't work? I've also tried manually including each swc as a library

EDIT: Worth noting that this is Flex 4.11 and AIR 3.9. Additionally, Grant Skinner's Asdocr app also fails with the same error.

Here are the imports from that class as well, just for good measure:

```
import com.vuria.events.ViewEvent;

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.graphics.SolidColor;

import spark.components.Button;
import spark.components.Group;
import spark.components.View;
import spark.primitives.Rect;
import spark.primitives.RectangularDropShadow;
```

Comment: looks like it has a problem compiling the code - have you tried adding the flex sdk as one of the source/lib paths? it's been ages since I've had to do it, so I don't have the syntax off hand. Try running asdoc on a simple file that doesn't extend anything to see if you get the same problem

Comment: @divillysausages I've tried that. Currently, I have it set as the `-compiler.library-path` option, but I have also tried it as everything from `-library-path` to `-source-path` to `-doc-sources`. It does work on a simple project, but I can't get it to work with anything related to the mobile sdk

Comment: try running it on a bare file, so at least we know if that's the problem

Comment: @divillysausages Was just editing my comment. I have tried that. Works fine on any project that doesn't include mobile components. My guess is, obviously, that those components are not being included. I've even tried adding those components manually

Comment: coming from here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ffa.html, some things to try: 1) "By default, the ASDoc tool compiles its input files against the library SWC files in the flex\frameworks\libs" - are the spark libs there, or somewhere else? 2) Try setting `-exclude-dependencies` to `true` 3) Try using `-exclude-[classes/dependencies/sources]` 4) Try adding the `-lenient` option (ignores errors)

Comment: also, what happens when you add the components manually? do you get the same error or a different one?

Comment: @divillysausages 1) Yes 2) Tried this 3) Tried this 4) If you look at the script I posted, I have been using the `-lenient` option 5) Same error. It's like nothing is different at all. EXACT same output

Comment: As an update, I've managed to get mobile components to load. But now NONE of the core Flash SDK is loading. It's telling me "definition Stage cannot be found", even. I am at a complete loss here.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use asdoc to generate Starling docs, with no joy, and came back across this question.

I was getting `"Incorrect number of arguments"` on a `requestContext3D()` call (i.e. basic Flash, like asdoc isn't using the right Flex/AIR version to generate).

Following the http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ffa.html and linked http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html, there's a better explanation of the properties.

What worked for me (either/or):

- Adding the `-strict=false`
- Specifying the target player, which would in turn link it against the proper playerglobal.swc: `-target-player=12.0`

A thing which really helped me was dumping the default config, so I could see all the default values for asdoc. You can do this via:

```
asdoc -dump-config config.xml
```

Looking through this file, I found:

```
<target-player>11.1</target-player>
```

So it was linking for Flash player 11.1, before the second parameter of the `requestContext3D` was added, hence my error.

In your case, I also saw that the default framework is set to `halo`, not `spark`, so changing it would probably help

Answer (score 0):

add the compiler arg `+configname=airmobile` and add the mobile theme swc to the library path. `-library-path+=${flexlib}/themes/Mobile/mobile.swc`